# Accessing salt in the constructor

Tags: ink

**tl;dr;**

How do I access salt, used for contract's instantiation, in its constructor?

**Longer version**

Contract's address is computed as `hash(caller ++ code_hash ++ salt)` meaning it is deterministic. Having an access to the `salt` part in the constructor would allow for creating access-guarded subcontracts, without having to resort to the *access control pattern* as the `AccountId` address can be calculated in the constructor itself and passed in as an argument.

```rust
struct MyInnerContract {
  owner: AccountId
}

impl MyInnerContract {
  pub fn new(owner: AccountId) -> Self {
    instantiate_contract(|instance: &mut MyInnerContract) {
      self.owner = owner;
    })
  }
}

//

struct MyOuterContract {
  subcontract_address: AccountId
}

impl MyOuterContract {
  pub fn new(inner_contract_code_hash: Hash) -> Self {
     let my_new_account_id = hash(Self::env().caller() ++ Self::env().own_code_hash() ++ Self::env().salt());
     
     MyInnerContractRef::new()
       .code_hash(inner_contract_code_hash)
       .exec_input(my_new_account_id)
       .instantiate().unwrap()
     ...
  }
}
```

Comment: This might be help in order to access `Salt` [access salt](https://paritytech.github.io/ink/ink_env/call/state/index.html)

Comment: `Salt` is an enum indicating the state of some call builder I guess. Doesn't look useful. I'm not sure if salt is accessible in the constructor, but I would not be surprised if it doesn't. If you just want to get the address of the new contract, inside the constructor you should be able to access `Self::env().callee()`, and outside the constructor you can convert the `InnerContractRef` to an account id.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @h4x3rotab, thanks for the suggestion but there's no `callee()` in the `Self::env()` : https://docs.rs/ink_lang/3.4.0/ink_lang/struct.EnvAccess.html if there was I wouldn't have this problem.

What I want to achieve is to calculate the `AccountId` of *external contract* that I am just instantiating, and pass that as an argument to the constructor of `InnerContractRef`. I thought that's clear from my code sample.

Comment: @h4x3rotab May be this could help. If you want to calculate of the AccountId of the contract which you instantiating, then I think you can use `Self::env().account_id()`. [You can look here](https://paritytech.github.io/ink/ink_env/fn.account_id.html)

Comment: @Ganesh11 when you call that in the constructor it will return the account ID of the caller, not the contract being instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot access the salt. For good reasons: The account id derivation algorithm isn't fixed and can be differ between chains. It would make your contract non portable. So you should not rely on that and this is why we don't expose this information.

That said, I think we might have a X Y problem here. In order to get help recommend to open a new question where you explain what you are trying to do and most importantly **why**. Then we might find a solution which does not require to rely on the implementation details of the account id derivation.